# Settings for CMD's console

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-console

As I already asked in the title I'd like to know the correct console settings path for the command prompt (CMD). I've already found `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`, but it looks like this isn't the correct one. I tried changing some values but they didn't appear in the command prompt.
I'm trying to set the console window transparency below 30%.

Comment: `HKCU\Console` has the default settings for the console. Subkeys of `HKCU\Console` have specific settings based on the initial window title when a console is created (e.g. `start "window title"  cmd.exe`), except if the creating process is run from a shortcut the console settings are saved in the shortcut itself instead of the registry. Note that nothing in the console subsystem depends on CMD. It's just a regular console client program.

Comment: @ErykSun Are you aware of any documentation outlining the settings load process for the `start "some title"` command? I've searched high and low on MSDN and cannot find this process anywhere. I've found an oddball article here and there, nothing official though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set the opacity below 30% because the valid range is 0x4D-0xFF. or 70-255 decimal.

More info [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/06/20/understanding-windows-console-host-settings/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm assuming it's not possible to change the valid range without risking sth.?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://superuser.com/a/1041164) answer, if you are using Windows 10 and run the command prompt with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, the settings are loaded from the `.lnk` files for both user and admin prompts at `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3\`. Right-click one of the `.lnk` files, select properties and you can change the settings from there.